# Hacer scroll hasta siguiente elemento con una clase concreta o al anterior

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de poder hacer smooth scroll hacia siguiente elemento con clase "destacado" o al anterior cuando hago click en los botones que estan fijos. No consigo que funcione este método y quizá hay alguna otra manera de simplificarlo.

Agradecería la ayuda de alguien.

La idea es que ante una lista larga de elementos destacados se pueda ir a cualquiera de ellos de manera ordenada hacia adelante o hacia atrás.

No estoy segura de si este sería el método adecuado para lo que necesito.

```js
<script>
$('.despues').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).addClass("marcado");
        $(this).parent().parent().addClass("destacado");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('marcado');
        $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("destacado");
    }
});
var $currentElement = $(".destacado").first();

$("#down").click(function () {
    var $nextElement = $currentElement.next('.destacado');
    if($nextElement.length) {
        $currentElement = $nextElement;
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
            scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    return false;
});

$("#up").click(function () {
    var $prevElement = $currentElement.prev('.destacado');
    if($prevElement.length) {
        $currentElement = $prevElement;
        $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
            scrollTop: $prevElement.offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    return false;  
});
</script>
```

```css
li {min-height: 100vw;}
.destacado {background:#ffaaaa;}
```

```html
<div style="position:fixed;right: 5vw;"><a href="#" id="down">Siguiente</a>
<a href="#" id="up">Anterior</a></div>
    <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li class="destacado">C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li class="destacado">G</li>
    <li class="destacado">H</li>
    <ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con

```
window.scrollTo({ top: $($(".destacado")[0]).offset().top,behavior:"smooth"})
```

donde $(".destacado")[0] seria tu elemento al que deseas ir. Solo lo puse asi para calar si funcionaba para el 0 o 1 o 2